# Removing rows with null values in any of a subset of columns (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

If I have the the following dataframe. If there is a null in either `Participation`, `Homework`, `Test`, `Presentation` (if there is a null is any of the four columns), then I want to remove that row. How do I achieve this in Pandas.

```
Name    Participation  Homework  Test Presentation  Attendance
Andrew  92             Null      85   95            88
John    95             88        98   Null          90
Carrie  82             99        96   89            92
Simone  100            91        88   99            90
```

Here, I would want to remove everyone except for Carrie and Simone from the dataframe. How do I achieve this in pandas?

I found this on Stackoverflow, which I think may help `df = df[pd.notnull(df['column_name'])]`, but is there anyway I can do this for all four columns (so a subset) instead of each column individually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can skip the replace if you use `ne`:

```
df[df.ne('Null').all(1)]

     Name  Participation Homework  Test Presentation  Attendance
2  Carrie             82       99    96           89          92
3  Simone            100       91    88           99          90
```

Answer (score 3):

Preparation, let's replace that string 'Null' with np.nan first.

Now, let's try this using `notnull`, `all` with axis=1:

```
df[df.replace('Null',np.nan).notnull().all(1)]
```

Output:

```
   Name  Participation Homework  Test Presentation  Attendance
2  Carrie             82       99    96           89          92
3  Simone            100       91    88           99          90
```

Or using `isnull`, `any`, and `~`:

```
df[~df.replace('Null',np.nan).isnull().any(1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

`replace` +   `dropna`

```
df.replace({'Null':np.nan}).dropna()
Out[504]: 
     Name  Participation Homework  Test Presentation  Attendance
2  Carrie             82       99    96           89          92
3  Simone            100       91    88           99          90
```